# EF Core 3.1 Key/Identity field being required by the Create form and I can't figure out why

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

EDIT/UPDATE:

I wanted to add something interesting. I removed the OrgId from the Create page and I can submit a new record, but then the database rejects it with an error that I cannot insert a NULL value into that table. It seems like I need to somehow not pass that field to SQL at all maybe? Hmm.

### -----------------------------

I do not want my code to generate any value for this OrgId field. The database does it by incrementing the previous value by 1. It is a traditional ID field in SQL. The problem is that every time I create a new record, the form on the Create page is requiring that I enter an OrgId. If I enter it then everything works ok, but the problem is I can't enter it since the database is in control of this field.

I have no data annotations for my OrgId field. I am using Fluent API for all my properties. Though, I have tried with annotations like [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)].

```
entity.HasKey(e => e.OrgId);

entity.Property(e => e.OrgId)
HasColumnName("OrgID")
```

I have tried appending all these values and more, but nothing is stopping this behavior. I have tried each one individually, no properties at all, combinations of all of the above.

```
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn() // deprecated
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .UseIdentityColumn();
```

The view is very simple and nothing here that should be requiring me to enter an OrgId.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="OrgId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="OrgId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OrgId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

The model is also very simple.

```
    public int OrgId { get; set; }
```

I have spent hours on this one little problem and it shouldn't be so difficult. I even rebuilt my entire project with the scaffolding again to make sure I didn't add anything unintentionally. Even in my new project I am getting the same behavior. I have even tried cheesy things like messing with the getters/setters. I feel like it is a property somewhere that is making the form require this field, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried adding [Key] annotation to model property and see if that works!

Comment: I have, yes. Thanks. I feel like I have tried every combination of the annotations as well as properties in the Fluent API. There has to be some combination of things I haven't tried yet, though. I consistently get "The OrgId field is required" on the form when I do not provide it. Then if I hide the field it sends a NULL to the database and the database throws an error back that it can't be NULL.

Comment: Are the names same in the model and database with same case?

Comment: Did you try removing the OrgId from the Html/Razor page and see if that works. Keep it in the model but try removing from the razor page.

Comment: I would have sworn they are, because it was all from the scaffolding. But, they are not. The database has OrgID. Code has OrgId. Hmm. .HasColumnName("OrgID") should be fixing that, though so it matches the database case even.

Comment: And I did try to remove it from the razor page. That is when it lets me submit the form, but it gives the SQL NULL error.

Comment: Check your database columns and check the properties. Is it an identity column with Auto_Increment to true?

Comment: You just hit the nail on the head. I assumed the database was auto incrementing and it is not. I am new to the company and just learning. I thought they would have had the database. Thank you for all of your time. That is the reason none of this is working! It is also not an identity column. They must be setting a value for it every time which is ridiculous to me, but that is the way it is.

Comment: I can answer the question so you can accept it. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, make sure the database column is an Identity Column with Auto_Increment true.

Comment: Yes. My issue is that the database I was working with was not the traditional style I am used to. The PK field is not an identity field and is user-generated in my case. Thank you Nirjhar for helping me get to the bottom of it.